# Convert keypress characters into integers in R

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a column of data in my df called rating_clean with one keypress entry per row, E.g. ['3'].

```
  subNum   age gend   hand  cond     trial word     rating    RT
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
1    100    19 female R     survival     0 truck    ['3']   2.83
2    100    19 female R     survival     1 diesel   ['3']   1.95
3    100    19 female R     survival     2 mountain ['1']   1.60
4    100    19 female R     survival     3 pepper   ['5']   1.77
5    100    19 female R     survival     4 book     ['4']   1.71
6    100    19 female R     survival     5 carbon   ['3']   1.61
```

As it is now, I get an error when I try to make a new df with the rating column as integers. My ultimate goal is to take the mean of that column. I have tried converting the column using as.numeric, but I get an error that says "NAs introduced by coercion."

This is the code that produces the error:

```
survival_rating_data <- as.numeric(rating_clean$rating)[rating_clean$cond=='survival']
```

How do I convert that entire column to integers? In other words, instead of ['3'], it should be 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove any non-numeric values in `rating` using `gsub` and convert it into numeric.

```
rating_clean$new_rating <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", rating_clean$rating))
```

A shorter way using `parse_number` :

```
rating_clean$new_rating <- readr::parse_number(rating_clean$rating)
```

You can now perform mathematical operations on `new_rating` column.